# Unable to execute Coded UI Tests on remote VM using TFS 2017 with VS 207 Enterprise (Could not load file or assembly)

Tags: tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-2017

I've installed VS 2017 Enterprise on both my Build server and Test server with the Coded UI Testing components installed, but my "Run Functional Tests" TF Build task still fails to resolve the reference to the CodedUITestFramework assembly.  All the assemblies are present on both VMs in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies" folder.

I've tried the following that hasn't worked!

1) Added the PublicAssemblies folder PATH environment variable

2) Added the assemblies to the GAC

Here is the error displayed in the console while running the TF Build/Release process:

MSTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class 'CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1' of assembly 'c:\Test\CodedUITestProject1.dll'. Reason Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

I'm at loss for how to enable my test DLL to resolve this assembly reference?

Comment: Could you manually run the Code UI test in remote VM with VS to see if it works?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Yes I successfully created a simple CUIT test by remoting to that VM.  I copied this project into source control and hooked it into the Release process where the solution is compiled, test agent deployed but the execution task still fails when resolving this assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple.  There is a "Version" drop-down at the top right hand corner of each Task that I was unaware of. :(  I needed to use "Version 2" of the **VS Test Agent Deployment** task so that I could properly configure it to deploy the VS 2017 Test Agent.  Once this was in place, the Deploy and Run Tests tasks run immediately without error!  Thanks again @Patrick-MSFT for your input along the way!

Answer (score 0):

To run Coded UI test, you have to configure the test agent to **interact** with the Desktop and build agent running as interactive Mode.

First please make sure you have enable it in **Agent Configuration** of  *Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment* task.

Besides to get more info for troubleshooting, you could also [enable debug mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) in the build definition.

---

**Update**

> - TFS 2017 RTM – TFS 2017 RTM shipped with ‘Visual Studio Test Agent
>     Deployment’ (v1) and ‘Run Functional Tests’ tasks that can be used in
>     the Team Build / Release Management scenarios. These tasks use the
>     Agents for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 package. As such, the tasks in
>     their current form can be used for running tests built using Visual
>     Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013. **They cannot run tests built using
>     Visual Studio 2017.**
> - TFS 2017 Update 1 – TFS 2017 Update 1 shipped with ‘Visual Studio    Test
>     Agent Deployment’ (v2) and ‘Run Functional Tests’ tasks that can be
>     used in the Team Build / Release Management scenarios. The test agent
>     deployment task has the ability to specify which Agent version (2015
>     or 2017) should be deployed. Based on the selection, the appropriate
>     agent will get deployed and can run tests built using Visual Studio
>     versions as described in the previous sections.

*Source Link: [Test Controller, Test Agent versions and their usage in different scenarios](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/11/23/test-controller-test-agent-versions-and-their-usage-in-different-scenarios/)*

Comment: Yes, just before the **Run Functional Tests** task I have the **Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment** task with the Agent Configuration set to Interactive.   Also, I connected to the VM using the same configured test user to watch the process run during the release processing and the host process does start up and appears that it is going to run but then just shuts down and never fires up the Browser used for executing the test.

Comment: @KJK According to  the assemblies are present on both VMs "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies". Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 is VS2015. Guess you  installed the old test agent  which for VS2015 and then installed path is still related to Visual Studio 14.0. Give a try with the latest test agent 2017. Download Link: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/  Choose Tools for Visual Studio 2017 and then select Agents for Visual Studio 2017 from the left navigation bar.

Comment: I only have VS 2017 Enterprise and Professional installed on these machines so I am not sure why they originally seemed to default to the **14.0** path. (never installed VS 2015)  Maybe because I had originally installed the VS Prof 2017 RC2? I also have this path _C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE_ which I believe is my real path for VS 2017.

Comment: I also downloaded the VS 2017 Tools Test Agent and it installed here _C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent_, however I now get **"Unable to find TestAgent installation path"** errors on the deploy test agent task when the test agent is pre-installed, so I can't get it to proceed to the Run Functional Tests task to see if it will work.

Comment: @KJK  According to the error:`Unable to find TestAgent installation pat` The location must be accessible by either the build agent (using the identity it is running under) or the test agent (using the identity configured above).  And the test agent must be manually downloaded, uploaded to a network location accessible to the agent, and the Test Agent Location parameter used to specify the location.  More details please refer: [Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment#arguments)

Comment: I successfully configured the agent to pull from a local agentlocation and install it, but this still has not resolved the runtime assembly load error on the **Run Functional Tests** task.  I uninstalled VS 2017 and TestAgent completely this time and watched as the TestAgent was installed into the **14.0** path which makes sense now since I see the agent is from **VS 2015 Update 3**.

Comment: I did finally realize that I needed to actually put the VS 2017 Test Agent on a share and have the **VS Test Agent Deployment** task deploy it which should resolve the Assembly reference problem once I get this task to run!  The problem is that it won't finish.  I have the _Interactive Process_ option set and have tried unchecking the _Update Test Agent_ option too...   I've also tried manually installing it and rebooting.                                 
`DistributedTests: Task 'DeployTestAgent' on machine 'vmcuit:5985' is taking time. Please Wait``

Comment: @KJK This seems to be a issue if  selected  the 'interactive process' checkbox on the deployment task. The solution is using same credentials for Test Agent and Build Agent. You could take a look at the same issue in GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2023

Comment: Yes I have seen that posting and I am using the same account/pwd for both the Agent Configuration and Test Machine Group within the **VS Test Agent Deployment** task configuration as well as in the Build Agent.  Additionally,  my process is hung up on the _DeployTestAgent_ step in the task so it does even get to the _ConfigureTestAgent_ step as is described in the posting.

Comment: @KJK Guess  I have found the root cause. You have to update your TFS2017 to update1. TFS 2017 RTM shipped with ‘Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment’ (v1) and ‘Run Functional Tests’ tasks that can be used in the Team Build / Release Management scenarios. These tasks use the Agents for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 package. As such, the tasks in their current form can be used for running tests built using Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013. They cannot run tests built using Visual Studio 2017. Details see my update answer.

Comment: I'm running TFS 2017 15.112.26307.0 (Tfs2017.Update1) not RTM and there is no option presented to specify which test agent.  I submitted a ticket to Microsoft and will be talking to them later today.   This was an Upgrade from "TFS 2013 Update 5" so maybe that is playing a role.

Comment: Thanks again for your patience and help with this problem.  I will come back and update this post once I have some answers as I am sure now that this is an issue with the upgrade process.  The Known Issue _Build doesn't work when upgrading to TFS 2017 Update 1 build 15.112.26301.0 from TFS 2013 or earlier_ referenced in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update1#knownissues came from our report in February/March.   I've now noticed other difference in the Tasks that lead me to believe the upgrade process has some other bugs in it.